# Java adding jbutton from Jframe1 to Jframe2

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jbutton

I hava  jframe1 and jframe2 which extends javax.swing.JFrame in netbeans.(in the same project).

jframe2 has a jpanel1. What is the wise way to share data between two forms ?

Comment: Please post the error and more information about your situation.

Comment: What error are you seeing? It's usually a good idea to provide all pertinent information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess NetBeans created a panel named `jPanel1` inside your `Jframe2`. The reason why you are getting an error is because NetBeans defaulted `jPanel1` accessibility to private and is not visible from the outside world. You should change its accessibility to `public` if you want to do that.

A more elegant way: you could add a method to `JFrame2` to take care of adding a button to its visual appearance. Something along these lines:

```
public class JFrame2 extends JFrame{
  //... 
  public void addButtong(JButton button){
     jPanel1.add(bt);
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
JButton bt = new javax.swing.JButton();
bt.setText("from jframe1 button1");
Jframe2.addButtong(bt);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have a reference to the actual instance of jframe2. If you don't understand this, you shouldn't be building a GUI yet, but you should start learning how to use Object Oriented Programming (OOP). If you actually understand this, you should know that the default access modifier for GUI components in NetBeans is private, which might cause the error that says the field jPanel1 isn't visible.

Answer (score 1):

Although `JFrame2` may *contain* a JPanel, it doesn't a have a *field* or *variable* called `jPanel1`, so you can't access it like this. (Internally it stores a collection of components, and you *can* access them through method calls - but not by 'name', and that's not an appropriate approach here).

You need to store a reference to your JPanel before adding it to its JFrame:

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
frame1.add(panel1);

JButton bt = new javax.swing.JButton();
bt.setText("from jframe1 button1");
panel1.add(bt);
```